# Passing data to a boolean method in another class and handling the response

Tags: c#

I have a boolean method I am trying to pass a decimal to, then based on some criteria for the received decimal return a boolean value. When passing a value to `Account.Deposit` I get the error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Account.Deposit(decimal)'

This is the method handling user input and then passing values onto my check/action method:

```
namespace BankApp
{
    public class DepositLogic
    {
        public void DoDeposit()
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter the amount you would like to deposit:");
            decimal DepositAmount;
            DepositAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            bool response;
            response = Convert.ToBoolean(Account.Deposit(DepositAmount));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the boolean method that is intended to return a `true`/`false` value to the method above as well as alter the balance variable based on input from the `DoDeposit` method

```
namespace BankApp
{
    public class Account
    {
        private Decimal _balance;

        public bool Deposit(decimal amountToAdd)
        {
            if(amountToAdd > 0)
            {
                _balance = _balance + amountToAdd;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My aim is to have a user enter an amount to "Deposit", that amount be passed to my `Account.Deposit` method, the balance variable be updated. Then a boolean value gets returned to alert the user if the action was successful/unsuccessful.

**Edit:**

If I instantiate my account in a different class, is it still possible to access it? Here is where my account is instantiated at the moment.

```
namespace BankApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Account account = new Account("Suriya's Account", 100000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, DepositAmount is a local variable, you should use camelCase to name it

Comment: Noted, thanks. @spidyx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are currently trying to access the `Deposit()` method in a static matter (`Account.Deposit()`) for this to work you have to mark the `Deposit()` method as `static`. But because you are accessing a field from within the `Deposit()` method (`_balance`) it is more likely you don't want the static approach.
In this case you have to instantiate your `Account` class first and then call the `Deposit()` method on the instantiated object like this:

```
public void DoDeposit()
{
    Console.Write("Please enter the amount you would like to deposit:");
    decimal DepositAmount;
    DepositAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
    bool response;

    var account = new Account();   // Instantiate object
    response = Convert.ToBoolean(account.Deposit(DepositAmount));  // Use instantiated object
}
```

If you want to have a further reading on the `static` topic in C# have a look at [this](https://theburningmonk.com/2010/07/static-vs-non-static-method-in-csharp/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer it makes sense. I have edited my post. If i instantiate the account class in a separate class to the class DoDeposit is in, can it still be accessed? thanks

Comment: @Xander No, you either have to instantiate the `Account` object on a shared location, like a global variable (I do not recommend this!), or you could pass the `Account` instance as parameter into your logic class (either in the constructor of the logic class or as parameter of the `DoDeposit()` method).

Answer (score 2):

`Account` is a class. You need to create an instance to call the `Deposit` method :

```
Account account = new Account();
response = Convert.ToBoolean(account.Deposit(DepositAmount));
```